# Data referencing to both tables in m:n relation

Tags: mysql, database, recursive-datastructures

I am working on a mysql based system to manage data from processing of food products. 
At this point I came across the following specific Problem:

I have a table A with some items:

```
Farmer      Quantity  
Farmer A    1000 kg  
Farmer B    500 kg
```

Then I have a table B which is an m:n agregation of data from table A:

```
Batch       Quantity     Quality etc.  
LI1         200 kg        ....  
LI2         12000 kg      ....
```

To represent the m:n relation I have a table AB which connects the two:

```
FK_Farmer    FK_Batch 
FarmerA      LI1   
FarmerB      LI1  
FarmerA      LI2
```

Now the problem: some of the batches in Table B are actually made up of other batches... which means they are recursively composed. I am intersted to know what is the best approach in terms of database design to implement this situation.

Should I include an additional foreign key in table AB referencing back to the batches table? Should I not enforce foreign keys and reference both the farmers and the batch table through the same column (and add a flag to indicate recursion or something)? 
Is there any other obvious solution I have ovelooked?

Being able to do drill-down queries for all data through direct MySQL would be nice, but is not necessarily required.

Comment: The batches I assume have some form of hierarchy, at least no loops, so a parent can not be a descendant of itself?  Also are batches ever split, so they are descendants of more than one batch?

Comment: Yes, there would be no loops; a batch cannot descent from itself. We have about 3-4 layers of products made from other products and they are organised in a straight hierarchy. Processingn of A leads to Products B and C, and processing of Product B leads to D,E and F. 


Batches can be made up of several other batches, yes; and one batch may go into more than one other batch.

 What I need to do is assure we can trace the batches back to their origin, while assuring weight conversions etc. is not in the scope of the project.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to represent the data is to add a Parent pointer to the Batch table. The root of a hierarchy would have a null in this field. Any non-root would point to its parent, which might in turn point to another parent, etc, for as many levels as you may have.

Querying such a structure is tricky because standard SQL has no way to process a tree. Oracle has a proprietary extension in their SQL dialect, but I don't think MySQL does. This means that to chase the whole tree, you have to either write code that loops through queries, or you have to write a query that does multiple joins for some arbitrary number of maximum levels.

But I don't know any easier way around it. Basically I'd plan on chasing the tree with code rather than a single query.

Answer (score 0):

If a parent batch can have multiple child batches, and a child batch can have multiple parent batches, then you need a new mapping table:

```
FK_ParentBatch  FK_ChildBatch 
LI1             LI5   
LI1             LI6  
LI2             LI5
LI2             LI3
LI3             LI4
```

Use foreign keys to make sure that the relations are maintained; but I don't know if the database can prevent you from getting into loops, you might have to rely on code or stored procs for that.